# How can i install or enables the innoDB in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to MySQL and want to have InnoDB table type for my database tables.   With me phpMyAdmin does not show me InnoDB Storage Engine.  I assume that InnoDB was not installed with MySQL Server installation.  How to install InnoDB Engine or InnoDB table type in MySQL.

I have check the phpMyadmin storage engine list but it show the innoDB disables state.

How can i install or enables the innoDB in MySQL.

Comment: @Manikandan Thangaraj: It will be better if you include the improvement that you suggested on the answer in your question, because it's discovered by you, not me :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Table-Types-or-Storage-Engines/InnoDB-Engine/How-to-install-Innodb-Engine):

> To get InnoDB enabled, open my.ini file and do the following:
>
> 1. Find skip-innodb directive from this file and place # before it to comment out. It will appear like #skip-innodb.
> 2. Save my.ini and restart the MySQL. 
>
> Then refresh phpMyAdmin, InnoDB Engine will be available to use.

To create a table using InnoDB engine, just declare your tables like this way -

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    -- Your table declaration
)Engine=InnoDB;
```