# Enable InnoDB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I want to use foreign key in MySQL. For that I needed to enable InnoDB feature. I have tried downloading latest version of MySQL Server from its official site. 
I went through similar questions on stackoverflow but they addressed different issues.
I have tried editing all the .ini files and enabling InnoDB properties by removing # in front of corresponding properties.
Then I restarted MySQL and checked status of InnoDB from MySQL Client using query/

```
 show engines;
```

It still shows InnoDB is disabled

I want to know steps of enabling the built in InnoDB feature for MySQL.
Here are the links to questions I visited:
[Ques1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757589/how-to-enable-innodb-in-mysql)

[Ques2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855118/how-can-i-install-or-enables-the-innodb-in-mysql)

[Official MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,121974)

I am newbie in MySQL.
I will be very thankful for any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check mysql log file. There could be some messages that may explain why InnoDB does not start. I suppose you don't have important InnoDB data. If so, try deleting **ib_logfile0.xxx** files and **ibdata** located in mysql data dir, then restart mysql to force those file to recreate. Also, check if innodb variables in my.cnf are properly configurated (For example, I have set memory for innodb_pool... to 1024G instead of 1024M, as a mistake).